# Manage Content Scroll of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have one scroll view in my application which has the pallete of colors
like this..
[image]

now in pro version of my application i want to show only 30 pallate of colors to user
and after he/she purchase the all colors than they have the full access to the color
how can i maintain this thing using content that scroll in scroll view
like in pro version scrollview have to scroll to only 30 colors and in full version it have to  scroll through all content
how can i manage that because in following code

```
svcolor.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0, 1970);
```

It will scroll through all content but when i tried to decrease the height it isn't scroll.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I did not get as to what

```
svcolor.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 1970);
```

good will it servea as you have kept width as ZERO. One of the appraoches that you can use is that make a function that First checks the version and accordingly create a scroll with specified number of images say something like

```
[self createPallete];
```

with some implementation such as

```
- (void)createPallete {
    //Create your scroll 
    if(proVersion == YES) {//proVersion is a BOOL to keep track
        svcolor.contentSize = CGSizeMake(svcolor.frame.size.width, HEIGHT+REQUIREDMARGINS @30objects);
    }
    else {
        svcolor.contentSize = CGSizeMake(svcolor.frame.size.width, HEIGHT+REQUIREDMARGINS @ALL Objects);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!